# State change does not trigger UI update on flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm currently trying to implement some basic bluetooth scanning functionality using flutter_reactive_ble to an App.
I'm also using flutter bloc for state management.
Now I have to Problem, that I find multiple bluetooth devices, but the UI doesn't get updated. When I'm using print commands track whats going on, I see the state updates correctly, but the UI is only updated once.

Here is the BLoc:

```
class BtConnectionBloc extends Bloc<BtConnectionEvent, BtConnectionState> {
  final BtConnectionsRepository _repo;
  late StreamSubscription _stream;
  

  BtConnectionBloc(this._repo) : super(const DevicesState()) {
    List<DiscoveredDevice> _devices = [];
    on<StartScanningEvent>((event, emit) {
      _stream = _repo.getDevices().listen((device) {
        final knownDeviceIndex = _devices.indexWhere((d) => d.id == device.id);
        if (knownDeviceIndex >= 0) {
          _devices[knownDeviceIndex] = device;
        } else {
          _devices.add(device);
          add(FoundDevices(deviceList: _devices));
        }
      });
    });

    on<EndScanningEvent>((event, emit) {
      _stream.cancel();
      _devices = [];
      emit(const DevicesState());
    });

    on<FoundDevices>((event, emit) {
      emit(DevicesState(deviceList: _devices));
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the repository class I've created:

```
class BtConnectionsRepository {
  final PairedDevicesRepository _deviceRepo = PairedDevicesRepository();
  final FlutterReactiveBle _ble = FlutterReactiveBle();

  static BtConnectionsRepository get instance => BtConnectionsRepository();

  Stream<DiscoveredDevice> getDevices() async* {

    yield* _ble.scanForDevices(withServices: []);
  }

  void connectToSavedDevices() async {
    PairedDevices _devices = await _deviceRepo.getPairedDevices();
    for (SavedDevice device in _devices.savedDevices) {
      _ble.connectToDevice(id: device.id);
    }
  }
}
```

On the UI Part, i'm adding an event in the didChangeDependencies override, with

```
    context.watch<BtConnectionBloc>().add(StartScanningEvent());
```

and the specific UI part is:

```
BlocBuilder<BtConnectionBloc, BtConnectionState>(
                buildWhen: (previousState, state) {
                  if(previousState.props.length != state.props.length){
                    return true;
                  }
                  else {
                    return false;
                  }
                },
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.0826,
                  ),
                  child: createDeviceList(state.props));
            },
          )
```

The function called there looks like this:

```
Widget createDeviceList(List<DiscoveredDevice> devices) {
    List<Widget> deviceWidgetList = [];
    for (var device in devices) {
      deviceWidgetList.add(PairingItem(
        device: device,
        onPressed: () {},
      ));
    }
    return Column(children: deviceWidgetList);
  }
```

I'm pretty clueless why it behaves like this, but I only get like the first update, showing a few devices, but every device found a bit later does not show up or causes an UI update.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of searching and trying, I've found the answer myself.
The Events / States of the Bloc extended Equatable, which caused the bloc not to refresh on emitting an updated state instead of a different state.